# Permission denied when trying to run Firefox on USB

Tags: usb, permissions, firefox

I feel like I'm doing this wrong, but I couldn't find any guides on how to install Firefox on a usb without portableapps. So basically I downloaded Firefox for Linux and extracted it to my usb, but it says permission denied.

[image]

Comment: Run mount in a terminal, and check that the "noexe" is not set on the mount. Check the /etc/fstab entry for how the mount is done.

Comment: What filesystem is on that USB? Not all support file permissions, which would explain why firefox doesn't become executable.

Comment: @mikewhatever It says vfat

Comment: @ubfan1 how do i check the "noexe"?

Comment: OK, vfat is one of those filesystems. Format it to ext4, then try again.

Comment: oh okay, but its gonna erase everything right?

Comment: Actually, you can mount it with `umask=000` option, so you might want to try that first. https://askubuntu.com/questions/866330/how-to-change-permissions-on-vfat-partition

Comment: It still doesn't work, so do i just reformat it?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run *terminal* as root and access the  USB device then run the file? (without sudo ofc), also try give access to folder could help

Comment: Yes I did, and it's the same thing

Comment: are you running the OS via VM?

Comment: uh i think, if crouton counts as a vm