# Cannot create a regular file - Permission denied upon copying a file, but files are copied with different permissions

Tags: boot, permissions, mount, virtualbox, filesystem

I am copying a set of files to a directory on which the SD card is mounted via

```
$ cp -a * /media/BOOT
```

but I get

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/media/BOOT/u-boot.img': Permission denied
```

With sudo

```
$ sudo cp -a * /media/BOOT
```

I get

```
cp: failed to preserve ownership for '/media/BOOT/u-boot.img': Operation not permitted
```

But in the `/media/BOOT`, I'm already seeing the files being copied but with different permissions.

```
// source permissions
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  367496 Aug 10 22:46 u-boot.img


// destination permissions
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  367496 Aug 10 22:46 u-boot.img
```

- Does anyone see why I'm getting the error and why are files being copied despite that?
- Is the change in permissions also why I can't possibly boot the boot image off the SD card?

Does running `chmod 777` in the destination folder sound like a good idea?

```
OS: 18.04.1-Ubuntu

SD card partition FS: vfat
```

Using it on a virtualbox but shouldn't matter

*Edit:*

Tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/866390/1152323) but no luck!

Comment: You haven't provided what OS & release you're using, nor what *file-system* is being used (can it correctly store POSIX details; or a set of *defaults* being masked over the non-existent permissions due to file-system in use)

Comment: added the OS & FS of the external drive's partition

Comment: `VFAT` filesystems don't support the Linux/Unix file ownership and permission bits. The whole-filesystem ownership and permission bits are set via `mount`. Look at `mount | grep 'BOOT` and read `man mount`, especially about `VFAT`.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't find the `man` page on `VFAT` quite useful. I found `sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000,exec /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1` this command on one of the SO links though